# Content Type Hub in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, content-type-hub

I have used Content Type Hub in On Premises and haven't had much issues but with online it's very difficult to use.

What I am seeing is, when we create a new site content type doesn't show up immediately but it takes hours.

We have a multi GEO and with Satellite location it takes more time compare to Default/Main tenant to get the content type to be available. Sometime it takes days(2-5 days).

I would really appreciate if someone can help if this can be speed up.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors and all of them out of your control. You share the particular stamp (farm) with other tenants. Those tenants may have a few hundred or hundreds of thousands of sites. Those same tenants may have 5 content types in the CT Hub or 5000.

Due to the poor performance of the timer job and the job architecture, unfortunately you have to wait it out. I've experienced up to 72 hour delays.

While you could open a support case with Microsoft to look at your particular tenant, there is likely little they can do to help -- but it may be worth opening one via admin.microsoft.com anyways.

Comment: Thanks, @Trevor. We are definitely going to open a case with Microsoft but as you mentioned we too have very little hope in that. CTH is becoming a pain for us. Can you recommend an alternative? Is it ok to create Fields and Content-Type at site collection level?

Comment: Yes, creating them on a per-site basis and then using another method to update them [globally] would be recommended. There are going to be investments into the CT Hub -- Microsoft is aware of the performance issues.